Im having bad thoughts, what do i do?
I'm not religious, I know I'm a horrible person, there's nothing to deny about that, but lately I've been getting horrible thoughts, about sexuality, about Islam, about everything, I know I'm bad but I don't recall being bad enough to receive these thoughts, I need help, I dont know whether its me or is it waswas?? I genuinely need help because I'm about to go crazy, I've been contemplating ending my life but I know it's not worth eternal hell, but I just can't live with myself anymore, please help.

Praise be to Allah
Praise be to Allah, Brother these thoughts are from shaytan seek refuge in Allah Rubulizza. Allah is the most merciful if you were to neglet Allah,sin, never pray, never fast, Become the most worst and filthiest person, and you seek sencere forgiveness in Allah and at the same time not associating parters with him, He will give you forgiveness that matches it. Every single time when you get waswas, say اعوذ بالله من الشيطان الرجيم and seek refuge in Allah from shaytan and go to a Muslim therapist or psychiatrist. Im so sorry this is happening to you May Allah Subhanawatalah help you Allahumaameen

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

I think you here, ask this question with your concern, shows it is a waswas. Praise to Allah you still have those kind of concern. Actually, I had through what happen to you, even I had through the time when I'm feeling I can't take it anymore, I frustrated. Untill I realized it's a waswas, it's a test too. Alhamdulillah, I don't have those kind of thoughts again.
I think I have to say. I had those kind of thoughts after I'm trying to be a good Muslim. I never missed my salah, even I did many salah sunnah. I'm trying to covering my self with the way Muslim women have to. I never had those thoughts before when I always commit sin, so I got that's from shaytaan.
Always making dua to Allah and read about the truth of the Qur an and Prophet Muhammad, Insya Allah your faith will be stronger.
